# Expectation and variance of $\int_0^t (W_s)^n ds$ for any positive integer $n$?

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

It is well known that the integral 
$$\int_0^t W_s ds,$$
where $(W_s)_s$ is a Brownian motion, can be derived using Ito's Lemma. More precisely, Ito's lemma on $d(tW_t)$ implies that 
$$d(tW_t) = tdW_t + W_t dt.$$ 
Therefore, 
$$\int_0^t W_s ds = tW_t - \int_0^t sdW_s.$$
Its mean and variance can be obtained from this expression.
This leads to my question below.

> Question: Given a positive integer $n,$ what is the mean and variance 
>   $$\int_0^t (W_s)^n ds?$$

Calculation above is for $n=1.$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the mean you can use Fubini's Theorem to change the order of integration 
$$ E\int_0^t (W_s)^n ds = \int_0^t E(W_s)^n ds$$
Then we can use the fact that $W_s \sim N(0,\sqrt{s})$ to obtain
\begin{align*}
E (W_s)^{2k+1} &= 0, k=0,1,2,...  \tag*{(odd n)} \\
E (W_s)^{2k} &= (2k-1)!!s^k, k=1,2,...  \tag*{(even n)} 
\end{align*}
Therefore,
\begin{align*}
E\int_0^t (W_s)^{2k+1} ds &= 0, k=0,1,2,...  \tag*{(odd n)} \\
E\int_0^t (W_s)^{2k}ds &= (2k-1)!! \int_0^t s^k ds = (2k-1)!! \frac{t^{k+1}}{k+1},  k=1,2,...  \tag*{(even n)} 
\end{align*}